# ACF is not showing the value when using get_field() or the_field()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields but even after setting the fields up properly and following the documentation to a tea, nothing is displaying. The H1 and p tags show up as empty. I have no idea why this is when the code seems correct. Thank you in advance for your help! :)

```
<main id="primary" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $hero_title = get_field( 'hero_title' );
        $hero_subtext = get_field( 'hero_subtext' );
        ?>
        <section id="hero">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="hero-title">
                    <h1><?php echo $hero_title; ?></h1>
                    <p><?php echo $hero_subtext; ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php get_footer(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right">

            </div>
        </section>

        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with this.

```
$hero_title = get_field( 'hero_title', get_the_ID() );

$hero_subtext = get_field( 'hero_subtext', get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: Still isn't displaying anything :(

Comment: where you are your adding code? in a post archive template? or in a custom loop or custom template?